# Downgrade Nintendo Switch v6.2.0?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I heard downgrade Nintendo switch is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading is not supported at all on the original firmware, so I assume you're asking about a currently modded device, or a device you plan to mod before downgrading.

One feature of Nintendo Switch hardware directly related to upgrades is called "the fuses". A fuse is a special region of internal memory which can only be written to (or "burned") one time, and once burned, it stays that way. Small upgrades don't burn fuses, but important upgrades do, and [6.2.0](https://switchbrew.org/wiki/6.2.0) was exactly one of these important upgrades. The number of burned fuses is checked by the bootloader every time your Switch starts up or wakes up, and the device will reset on a mismatch.

So no, there's no way for you to roll back to an earlier original firmware.

Comment: The efuses are not really a part of the internal memory-- it's a special section in SoC, though it does get read to the memory at boot, yes. Number of fuses being lower than firmware (i.e updating without burning fuses) is only checked on boot, while number being higher than firmware (i.e downgrading) is checked on both boot and wake, so normally you can't wake from sleep mode when you downgrade and boot through a custom bootloader with no fuse checks, however as of the release of dormez vous exploit, you can go to sleep and wake no matter your state of fuses ALA the bootloader supports it.

Comment: If you upgraded without burning your fuses (through booting to RCM on first boot after update and use of a custom bootloader after that, through updating with AutoRCM enabled while booting into Atmosphere CFW or through use of ChoiDujourNX with AutoRCM enabled), you can very well downgrade (you can restore an old NAND+BOOT0/1 backup or use ChoiDujourNX with console reinitialization) and boot without needing to go through RCM on every boot.

Comment: However, if you're fine with having to go through RCM on every boot, you can simply use a tool like ChoiDujourNX (with console reinitialization) and downgrade to any firmware you want, however there is no point to this whatsoever. [Also, obviously to do any of this, you need a console vulnerable to Fusee Gelee](https://akdm.github.io/ssnc/checker/).